# Weekly repayments of a loan excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a spreadsheet to show me when I will pay off my loan. Lets say my loan is €1,500 and I don't pay interest on it. I am paying it off in weekly payments which increase by €2 each week. For example week 1 I pay €2 off the loan and week 2 I pay €4 off it and week 3 I pay €6.

On that logic I would have it paid off by week 39 of a year, but I want to show how many weeks I have left to pay based on what week of the year I have saved up until.

I also make an additional €100 payment once every 4 weeks

Comment: Please show us the effort you have already put in.  Stack Overflow is not a free code-writing service.

Comment: I was trying to post a screenshot of my spreadsheet but it won't let me post pictures as I am new to stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming 1500 loan, no interest, weekly repayment 2 x week number (2, 4, 6, ...) and 100 every 4 week (so when week number divisible by 4).

```
Loan                   1500         

Loan repay per week       2         
Loan repay per 4 weeks  100         


Time    Loan at start   Regular repayment   Adhoc repayment Loan at end
0   1500            1500
1   1500    2   0   1498
2   1498    4   0   1494
3   1494    6   0   1488
4   1488    8   100 1380
...
```

You are repaid by 28 week.

```
....
26  250 52  0   198
27  198 54  0   144
28  144 56  100 -12
```

### FORMULAS

```
Loan    1500(i.e. B2)           

Loan repay per week 2(B4)           
Loan repay per 4 weeks  100(b5)         

Time    Loan at start   Regular repayment   Adhoc repayment Loan at end
0       =B2                                                 =B8-C8-D8
1       =E8     =$B$4*A9     =IF(MOD(A9,4)=0,$B$5,0)        =B9-C9-D9
2       =E9     =$B$4*A10   =IF(MOD(A10,4)=0,$B$5,0)        =B10-C10-D10
3       =E10    =$B$4*A11   =IF(MOD(A11,4)=0,$B$5,0)        =B11-C11-D11
```

drag down formulas. Look for where it goes negative.